# Single node AWS OKD cluster not responding after restart

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, okd

My OKD 4.8 single node deployment has been up for more than a month now. Then today it started acting (pods not being created). So I thought maybe I reboot the node. I shut it down via the AWS console. And then I started it again.

However, after restart, it is not responding. The node is running but OKD is not accessible. Neither the console nor the API can be reached. Any oc command results in  "The connection to the server api.api1.hostname.info:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

The domain name and all zones are hosted by AWS.

Any troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? Usually it takes time after node restart for kubernetes to run its components. Also you can check that CRI (e.g. docker) is running, kubelet is running.

Comment: I was not able to resolve the issue, so I nuked the instance and recreated it. To @moonkotte. I even waited a day and retried to start it, to no avail.